# is there a way to write a clojure function that destructures a map and returns any portion of the map?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I would like to write a function that accepts a specific structure of a map and returns (prints out) any portion of the map I want. Is this possible?

I haven't been successful so far. The following below are the functions I wrote to print portion a, b and c of the map but i seem to be missing some logic in this whole thing.

The test map is {:nums {:test number?}}. **My true goal is to return the test value i.e number? or whichever value the user wishes to test e.g symbol? or vector?.** This is why I have chosen to use this method.

I wish to understand the logic that's why I have chosen to return all the parts of the map i.e a, b, c.

Thanks.

```
(defn des [mapp]
  (let [[a [b c]] [mapp]]
    (println (str a)))
  )
=> #'user/des
(des {:nums {:test number?}})
{:nums {:test #object[clojure.core$number_QMARK_ 0x1089d00e "clojure.core$number_QMARK_@1089d00e"]}}
=> nil


(defn des [mapp]
  (let [[a [b c]] [mapp]]
    (println (str b)))
  )
=> #'user/des
(des {:nums {:test number?}})

=> nil



(defn des [mapp]
  (let [[a [b c]] [mapp]]
    (println (str c)))
  )
=> #'user/des
(des {:nums {:test number?}})

=> nil
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  Get the :test for when :nums is passed?  I think you are best off with `get-in` or you can destructure like this: `(let [{{test :test} :nums} {:nums {:test number?}}] test)` It would really help if you could be more clear what your ultimate goal is (i bet it's not println something)

Comment: hello @cfrick, Thanks for the response. My goal is simply to return what the user wishes to test for i.e number?, symbol? vector? etc. I don't want to precode it, I want it to be provided by the user.

Comment: But how would your code know, what the user wants?  Either it's some path to the test the user and your code share - or your code somewhat has to "find" a map with a :test key; and if so, up to what level deep?

Comment: yes, the code has to find the value for the test value and return it. The map would always be in this form {:nums {:test number?}} but the test value could change to whatever the user wants e.g symbol?.

Comment: Sounds like you want `(get-in mapp [:nums :test])` as @cfrick suggested.

Comment: You're using [sequential destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring) when you ought to be using [associative destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_associative_destructuring), as [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288461/1562315) shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defn des [mapp] 
  (let [m mapp
          {x :nums y :vects z :syms} m
          {a :test} x
          {b :test} y
          {c :test} z
          ]
    (println x)
    (println y)
    (println z)
    (println a)
    (println b)
    (println c)
    )
  )
=> #'user/des

(des {:nums {:test number?}})
{:test #object[clojure.core$number_QMARK_ 0x48c86e76 clojure.core$number_QMARK_@48c86e76]}
nil
nil
#object[clojure.core$number_QMARK_ 0x48c86e76 clojure.core$number_QMARK_@48c86e76]
nil
nil
=> nil

(des {:nums {:test number?}, :vects {:test vector?} :syms {:test symbol?}})
{:test #object[clojure.core$number_QMARK_ 0x48c86e76 clojure.core$number_QMARK_@48c86e76]}
{:test #object[clojure.core$vector_QMARK___5399 0x17d504aa clojure.core$vector_QMARK___5399@17d504aa]}
{:test #object[clojure.core$symbol_QMARK_ 0x4593ff34 clojure.core$symbol_QMARK_@4593ff34]}
#object[clojure.core$number_QMARK_ 0x48c86e76 clojure.core$number_QMARK_@48c86e76]
#object[clojure.core$vector_QMARK___5399 0x17d504aa clojure.core$vector_QMARK___5399@17d504aa]
#object[clojure.core$symbol_QMARK_ 0x4593ff34 clojure.core$symbol_QMARK_@4593ff34]
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, the problem at hand is to find the any `:test` key in a map of maps.  So `some`+`vals` can be used to produces such a result:

```clj
user=> (some :test (vals {:nums {:test number?}}))
#<Fn@45297e7 clojure.core/number_QMARK_>
```

This is aggressive, since it assumes, `:test` (as a function) can be called on each map value (at least until the result is found).